# How can I distinguish between Unix and Android on NetStandard 2.0?

Tags: c#, mono, runtime, .net-standard

I need to distinguish between Android and Unix at runtime in a .NetStandard 2.0 library. The library must compile for .Net Standard so an `#if ANDROID` solution is not suitable.
Environment.OSVersion returns `Unix 3.18.14.12365438` on Android.

Other solutions like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo/ wont work on Android because then the Mono Profile is missing at runtime and are only possible if the library is compiled for multiple targets.

Is there a way to detect this at runtime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something environmental.

Without getting into native shared libraries (`.so`) and the permission issues, API differences, etc.. `DLLImport` externs are not a great option.

An OS file existent can be troublesome due to sandboxing so `File.Exists` should be avoided.

But Android does have a cmd `getprop` that is available to any user (i.e. non-root), is always in the shell path and thus if it executes and returns a value you are on Android. Cheap but it works...

```
public static class AndroidTest
{
    static bool? isAndroid;
    public static bool Check()
    {
        if (isAndroid != null) return (bool)isAndroid;
        using (var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "getprop";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "ro.build.user";
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            try
            {
                process.Start();
                var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                isAndroid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? (bool?)false : (bool?)true;
            }
            catch
            {
                isAndroid = false;
            }
            return (bool)isAndroid;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Of course someone could spoof a `getprop` cmd and its return value to fool this, **or any other environmental check**, but unless you have access to Android native APIs and have a desire to stay 100% portable, I do not see a way around it...